# Execute management command from admin with arguments

Tags: django

My little podcast backend written in Django contains a ShowModel. I have also written a custom management command to update episodes for each show from an external API.

For ease of use I'd now like to put a button next to the list of shows in the Django admin to be able to update them from there. I know there's `call_command()` that also takes the argument but I'm getting a bit stuck in how to bring this into the admin area where the shows are already. Also, if possible I'd also pass the output to the web admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib https://github.com/vint21h/django-mcadmin
Or try to read the code and pull some pieces to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I was solving the same puzzle of running management commands from the admin interface, so here is what I found [pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ django-run-command](https://test.pypi.org/project/django-run-command/)

This package helps you to run management commands from the admin dashboard